# How to add an extra column for editing 'Rows' of data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL statement that populates my table (the SQL statement is a simple select).

My table is as follows:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

// Table start.
html.Append("<table  class= 'display table table-bordered table-striped' id='dynamic-table'>");

foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    html.Append("<th>");
    html.Append(column.ColumnName);
    html.Append("</th>");
}

html.Append("</tr>");

//Building the Data rows.
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    html.Append("<tr>");

    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<td>");
        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
        html.Append("</td>");
    }

    html.Append("</tr>");
}

//Table end.
html.Append("</table>");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```

What I want is to have an extra column called `Edit`, and the rows must be an edit link. I should be able to figure out how to point the edit link to my rows of data. But for now, could someone help me with this issue, as I'm fairly new to programming.

Comment: You can do it in many ways. However, if your sql statment brings all data from db, probably you don't need to show the id in the view, so for the id column show a button.  include a if condition when you populate the rows and add a edit button instead of the data(id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write some thing like this

```
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                if(column.ColumnName=='id')
                {
                    html.Append("<button type = \"button\" > Edit!</button>");
                }else{
                      html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);  
                }                    
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");

        }
```

Comment: It is only allowing me to add 1 char in the 'id' field? Is there a fix for this? And btw, im not pulling any information for the id in my select statement. Does that matter?

Comment: Okay i fixed the 1 char in the id field. But it isnt populating my table with any buttons?

Comment: It's all depends on your need, and I hope you need the id for the edit, so you can pull the id and use the id to create the link to edit.

Comment: Yes i figured i needed the Id field, but mine was named differently. Now im just trying to figure out how to add an href link to that button. Keep getting errors.

Comment: Try some thing like this
    html.Append("<button type = \"button\" href=\"..\\Edit?Id="+ row[column.ColumnName] +"> Edit!</button>");

Comment: I Edited it to this, but its still not even picking up the href link. Nothing happens when i click. Do you know why?

html.Append("<button type = \"button\" href=TripPrefixAdministration.aspx?TripPrefixId=" + row[column.ColumnName] + "> Edit</button>");